# How do you programatically add a user to a user entry field

Tags: plugin-development, users

I have created a controller called myPlugin_Controller.php

This is the following code inside it.

```
 <?php
class myPluginController extends BaseController
{
    public function actionSave()
    {

        $this->requirePostRequest();

        // get all the post variables
        $elementId = craft()->request->getPost('elementId');
        $userId = craft()->request->getPost('userId');

        // set the name of the field you want to update
        $fieldHandle = 'friends';

        // based on the element and field vars, get the models for each
        // using the elements and fields services
        $element = craft()->elements->getElementById($elementId);
        $field = craft()->fields->getFieldByHandle($fieldHandle);

        // store the current ids into a variable
        $currentIds = $element->{$field->handle}->ids();

        // merge the new id into the current ids
        $newIds = array_merge($currentIds, (array) $userId); 

        // save the new array of ids, using the relations service
        craft()->relations->saveRelations($field, $element, $newIds);

        // redirect to the redirect url
        $this->redirectToPostedUrl();

    }
}
?>
```

This is my code in an html file, it is submitting some data however it returns a 404 error.

```
   <form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8"> 
                  {{ getCsrfInput() }}
              <input type="hidden" name="action" value="myPlugin/Save">
              <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/success">

              <input type="hidden" name="elementId" value="{{ user.id }}">

              <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="{{ currentUser.id }}">

              <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
          </form>
```

i'm not too sure where its going wrong now.

Also if your wondering why its called user this is why
        {% set user = craft.users.username( craft.request.segment(2) ).first() %}
Do you know where I am going wrong now any tips or help is all appreciated! :)

Still not working I have looked at craft cms documentation online i've followed your steps and there steps.

Is there anything you can still see that is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You will need a custom plugin to do this.

I'll assume that you're familiar with that process.

You can build a form in your template like this, passing in the entry ID you want to add the user to and the user ID you want to add.

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8"> 
    {{ getCsrfInput() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="myPlugin/save">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/success">

    <input type="hidden" name="elementId" value="{{ entry.id }}">

    <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="{{ currentUser.id }}">

    <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then, you'll need a controller action in your plugin to which you submit a POST request from a form.

```
public function actionSave()
{
    $this->requirePostRequest();

    // get all the post variables
    $elementId = craft()->request->getPost('elementId');
    $userId = craft()->request->getPost('userId');

    // set the name of the field you want to update
    $fieldHandle = 'myUserField';

    // based on the element and field vars, get the models for each
    // using the elements and fields services
    $element = craft()->elements->getElementById($elementId);
    $field = craft()->fields->getFieldByHandle($fieldHandle);

    // store the current ids into a variable
    $currentIds = $element->{$field->handle}->ids();

    // merge the new id into the current ids
    $newIds = array_merge($currentIds, (array) $userId); 

    // save the new array of ids, using the relations service
    craft()->relations->saveRelations($field, $element, $newIds);

    // redirect to the redirect url
    $this->redirectToPostedUrl();

}
```

**EDIT:**

It's very important that you follow the naming conventions in the docs.

You controller class should be named MyPluginController, which would then make the action in the form myPlugin/save (controller and action get removed from the exposed plugin and action names).

Also the redirect should be a page on the side where you want the user to go after being added, not pointing to your plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Jeremy thanks for the help it is getting me on the right track what you have given me thanks :), However I still haven't quite solved it, I found documentation on how to use custom controllers. This is where I am at now.

I have created a controller under the controllers folder in the plugins directory with the file name of myPlugin_myController.php

This is the following code inside it.

```
<?php
class myPlugin_myController extends BaseController
{
    public function actionSave()
    {

        $this->requirePostRequest();

        // get all the post variables
        $elementId = craft()->request->getPost('elementId');
        $userId = craft()->request->getPost('userId');

        // set the name of the field you want to update
        $fieldHandle = 'friends';

       // based on the element and field vars, get the models for each
       // using the elements and fields services
       $element = craft()->elements->getElementById($elementId);
       $field = craft()->fields->getFieldByHandle($fieldHandle);

       // store the current ids into a variable
       $currentIds = $element->{$field->handle}->ids();

       // merge the new id into the current ids
       $newIds = array_merge($currentIds, (array) $userId); 

       // save the new array of ids, using the relations service
       craft()->relations->saveRelations($field, $element, $newIds);

       // redirect to the redirect url
       $this->redirectToPostedUrl();

    }
}
?>
```

This is my code in an html file, it is submitting some data however it returns a 404 error.

```
 <form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8"> 
              {{ getCsrfInput() }}
              <input type="hidden" name="action" value="myPlugin/myController/actionSave">
              <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="myPlugin/myController">

              <input type="hidden" name="elementId" value="{{ entry.id }}">

              <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="{{ currentUser.id }}">

              <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
          </form>
```

Do you know where I am going wrong now any tips or help is all appreciated! :)

Comment: You controller should be named MyPluginController, which would then make the action in the form myPlugin/save (controller and action get removed from the exposed action). Also the redirect should be a page on the side where you want the user to go after being added, not pointing to your plugin.

Comment: Also, it'd be best to update your question with this, so that we can better help you.

Comment: @Alistair: This isn't an answer, it's an extension of your original question. Please edit this information into the original question... we'll be deleting this non-answer.

Comment: @JeremyGimbel I have updated the code up the top, still no luck :/ but I think we are getting closer.

Comment: I updated my answer. Your controller class is still named incorrectly.

Comment: @JeremyGimbel I'm not sure why its not working but it is still not working is there anything you can still see?

Comment: @JeremyGimbel I'm a bit suspicious of my controller not even being triggered at all

Comment: Based on the code in your question, you still haven't followed the correct naming conventions. Capitalization matters. This would very much prevent the controller from executing. I would suggest reviewing the docs (https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/controllers) or perhaps examining some of the other available plugins (perhaps P&T's own contact form plugin) to compare your naming and structure.